# Send other input value

Tags: php, html, events, handler, dispatcher

I'm now looking for `Event_Handler & Dispatcher` class, and there was that moment, to make individual class for each event.

For example I have database with some record, and i want to choose between two actions Edit & View records.

So I need to create two files `class.Handler_Edit` & `class.Handler_View`, and then depending on pressed input

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit"/> 
OR
<input type="submit" name="action" value="View"/>
```

I need to get value from `$_POST['action']` and call, for example, the correct class

```
'class.Handler_' . $_POST['action'] . '.php'
```

and then start for example

```
class.Handler_View.php
```

(depending on selected input).

All cool, works! But the problem is, that i'm using russian words for input value. Not `value="View"` & `value="Edit"`, but `value="Посмотреть"` & `value="Редактировать"`.

And then i can't call class

```
class.Handler_Редактировать.php
```

I found a solution, that i can use `buttons` instead `inputs`, for example:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="edit">Редактировать</button>`.
```

But is it the correct way to solve that problem?

Maybe it's not the best decision to renounce the use of `inputs` and use only `buttons`?

Comment: Ideally you are changing the action="" to reflect the action. Don't depend on the value of a $_POST var, but instead on the URL. For example, myform/edit, or myform/view

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem would be to use if statements! Here is a code sample:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "Посмотреть") {
    // do something with 'class.Handler_View.php'
} else if ($_POST['action'] == "Редактировать") {
    // do something with 'class.Handler_Edit.php'
} else {
    //uh oh, you didnt get View or Edit!
}
```

This is also much safer, as the end user can change the value of the form extremely easily! Also with this method, you will be able to use either the buttons or the inputs!

Comment: Thanks, but not the best decision. If i'll have more than 2 actions, i would must to check all of them, and there will be too many if..else's. 
In that case, better to use associative array. `array('Редактировать' => 'edit', ...);`

Comment: @kxc Very true. Looks like you have found your own solution!